# React app shows a blank page after the deployment

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I deployed my website that uses React and Django. It works fine, but only with Django part. When I try to go to any react path, it simply shows the blank page(which is from build folder).

In the console I see three errors

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

Why is that? I have no idea what to do.

My deployed website: https://oridal.herokuapp.com/

If you need more code, feel free to ask for one

Comment: Can you paste the results of `heroku logs --tail` ?

Comment: There is too much code after this command. But I think it's fine, because everything has 200 status and there is nothing red

Comment: Do you have the appropriate buildpacks installed?  I don't use Django but perhaps this article might give you some clues?  https://alphacoder.xyz/deploy-react-django-app-on-heroku/

Comment: I deployed the web site using this article :-)

Comment: I can give you the git repository  https://github.com/danilF4/react_and_django

Comment: Open the console. You are returning pure HTML in your JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was not able to understand the cause of my problem.

But I decided to do it another way, so I just took already existing application that works on React and Django, then I cloned it and started to copy and paste my own files to this new application.

Here is the link to the GitHub repository of this [application](https://github.com/justdjango/DjReact).

I hope, it'll help.